# Get the status of DHL and Hermes Shipments via API using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dhl

Our company is doing a shipment of more than 3000 orders per day and now , we need to get the status of individual shipments send by DHL and Hermes carriers.

We have the tracking numbers with us and the order numbers that is send to DHL or Hermes.

Any suggestions on how we can do it via Python?
Any leads wil be very helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The main Python packages for calling APIs are [requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) and [urllib3](https://pypi.org/project/urllib3/).  I would start with `requests` as in my experience it is more straight forward to get started with.